# How can I override a pyqt4 QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

I am trying to adapt a photo viewer in pyqt4 (I got the code from another question on this site). By default, the mouse wheel zooms, and the left mouse button is used to pan/drag (don't know exactly what to call this) the image. I want to add the capability to get pixel information when left-clicking on the image, so I intended to have a button to change from 'pan' mode to 'pixel info' mode. My attempt to do this is below but it is not behaving as I intended.

When I load an image with the first GUI button and zoom in on the image, if I don't pan/drag the image, then clicking the second GUI button disables the pan/drag and, when I click on the image, provides pixel info for pixel where I clicked. This is what I expected.

However if I zoom in and then pan/drag the image first, when I click on the second GUI button, it no longer disables the pan/drag and doesn't print pixel info.

For some reason I don't understand (and which I hope somebody can enlighten me with) dragging the image after zooming seems to lock in the pan/drag method and not allow me to change it. Can anyone tell me why.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class PhotoViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def fitInView(self):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                         viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self.centerOn(rect.center())
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.fitInView()
        else:
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            if event.delta() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def printPixInfo(self,event):
        print event.pos()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadImage(self):
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap('pic.jpg'))

    def pixInfo(self):
        print 'Now in pixel info mode'
        self.viewer._photo.mousePressEvent = self.viewer.printPixInfo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would also like to know, once I have successfully changed the mouse click method, what the syntax is for returning the mouse left-click back to the default pan/drag behaviour.

I am a python novice, so try not to criticise me too much please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that by completely overriding `mousePressEvent` you are losing all of the default behaviour (e.g. panning with mouse). It would be better to use a custom signal to notify when the photo has been clicked. And since the graphics-view already has an API for changing the drag-mode, you could add a slot for switching modes:

```
class PhotoViewer(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)    
    ...

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(QtCore.QPoint(event.pos()))  
        # keep the default behaviour
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

These two new APIs can then be used to give you the functionality you want:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # add a line-edit to display the position info
        self.editPixInfo = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        ...
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)

    def pixInfo(self):
        # switch modes
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        # handle photo-click signals
        if self.viewer.dragMode() == QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
```

Comment: Well that's done exactly what I wanted so thank you very much, you are a star. As I mentioned, I'm a python novice and I'm still getting used to the whole OOP way of doing things, and it would have taken me a long time to get to the point where I would have known which class methods were available. I can understand how you've made it work (mostly) so thanks for the lesson. But could you clear up one point please. What is the exact purpose of the super function in your modified mousePressEvent method?

Comment: @AndrewBirch. It calls the base-class method so that the default behaviour is maintained.

Comment: So by calling the super function, your mousePressEvent code is essentially appended to the beginning of the base class method's code rather than replacing it? Is that right?

Comment: @AndrewBirch. Yes - you're just observing the event and providing some extra functionality before passing it on unchanged.

Comment: Can you limit the code to only what has changed, or is it all over the place? The text suggests it should only be a couple of changes, but I didn't check carefully.

Comment: @Schollii. You're right - my original answer was a bit lazy. I have simplified things to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for updating